# Access-Control-Allow-Origin denied spotify api

Tags: javascript, jquery, rest, spotify

I'm trying to access to the Spotify API token like so:

```js
$.ajax({
  url: "https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token",
  type: 'POST',
  contentType: "application/json; charset=\"utf-8\"",
  crossDomain: true,
  data: {
    grant_type: "authorization_code",
    code: code,
    redirect_uri: "http://www.bancadigital.com.br/spotifyteste/callback.html"
  },
  processData: false,
  dataType: "json",
  headers: {
    Authorization: "Basic " + utf8_to_b64(key)
  },
  success: function( response ) {
    alert(response.access_token);
  },
});
```

but the service returns the following error:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://www.bancadigital.com.br' is therefore not allowed access.

Does anyone know how I can access the service?

Comment: If they don't allow you - you cannot do that using client side JS.

Comment: I haven't used the Spotify API myself, but this example might help.  https://github.com/spotify/web-api-auth-examples/blob/master/client_credentials/app.js

Answer (score 18):

The request to `https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token` needs to be made server side and not as an AJAX request.

This way your `key`, which contains the credentials for your application, won't be exposed. Also, the Spotify server will be able to redirect the request to the `redirect_uri` together with the access token.

An alternative is to use the [implicit grant flow](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-api/concepts/authorization) where you can run everything client side, but you will not get a refresh token.

I would recommend you to review the [Spotify Web API Authorization Guide](https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/authorization-guide/), check [the GitHub repo with auth examples](https://github.com/spotify/web-api-auth-examples) and take a look at the [libraries and wrappers](https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/code-examples/#libraries) that make it easier to implement the OAuth flow.