# Angular 5 - HTTP Post x-www-form-urlencoded

Tags: angular, http, post, spotify

So I've been learning Angular and am just about finished with my first end to end application. The app utilizes Spotify's public API to search music and play previews of tracks.

I am having an issue with writing my Http Post method. This post method returns .json that includes an access-token that I use to access and make get calls to the API. My Post method works just fine in Postman but I can't figure out how to write it in Angular.

This is what I have in Postman:

```
POST /api/token HTTP/1.1
Host: accounts.spotify.com
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Authorization: Basic Y2M5ZjgzZWM1NGRkNDVlYTg1NGEzZDdhNmRmOGU2ZjY6YjNhY2FkMDc4YjkxNDNlZTkwNzgxMzBlNGJiNDVjZTI=
Cache-Control: no-cache
Postman-Token: 8e3e0924-1ad7-97b4-3aee-533486854434

grant_type=client_credentials
```

That post works perfectly and returns the access_token I need.

This is what I have in Angular:

```
    constructor(private _http:Http) {
    this.clientSecret = "Y2M5ZjgzZWM1NGRkNDVlYTg1NGEzZDdhNmRmOGU2ZjY6YjNhY2FkMDc4YjkxNDNlZTkwNzgxMzBlNGJiNDVjZTI=";
    this.authURL = "https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token";
    let header = new Headers();
    header.append("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    header.append("Authorization", "Basic " + this.clientSecret);
    this._http.post(this.authURL, "grant_type=client_credentials", {headers: header})
    .map(res => res.json())
    .subscribe(res => {this.authToken = res.access_token})
  }
```

I get this error:

```
Failed to load https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token: 
Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: 
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested 
resource. 
Origin 'http://localhost:4200' is therefore not allowed access.
```

Obviously sounds like I'm missing a header but I think it's the way I am posting the body: "grant_type=client_credentials". Also, something to do with the fact its of type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

Any help would be much appreciated, thanks!

P.S. This is my first post, I hope everything is formatted okay.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Access-Control-Allow-Origin denied spotify api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28389699/access-control-allow-origin-denied-spotify-api)

Comment: It's a CORS issue, you need to make that call from a server, not from the browser. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28389699/access-control-allow-origin-denied-spotify-api

Comment: Trying to build a server with Node.js. Hopefully this resolves the issue.

Answer (score 0):

There is Nothing to do with `Content-Type`.The key of the problem is that you have to specify a **Redirect URIs** of your Spotify APP.After that, the URL, `http://localhost:4200` in this case, would be allowed to access the API endpoint of Spotify.See details in [Spotify Developer Doc](https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/tutorial/)

Comment: Tried this... Got the same error through the console. I think it's the way I am sending the body portion of the post. Appreciate the quick response though.